# MySql , JOIN and Group By query is Using temporary and Filesort

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, filesort

I have 2 tables as below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `ox_campaigns` (                                                       
    `campaignid` mediumint(9) NOT NULL auto_increment,                                
    `campaignname` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',                                  
    `clientid` mediumint(9) NOT NULL default '0',                                                                                                    
    `is_deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',                                        
    PRIMARY KEY  (`campaignid`),                                                      
    KEY `ox_campaigns_clientid` (`clientid`)                                          
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE `ox_clients` (                                   
  `clientid` mediumint(9) NOT NULL auto_increment,            
  `agencyid` mediumint(9) NOT NULL default '0',               
  `clientname` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',                                                                
  `is_deleted` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,                           
  PRIMARY KEY  (`clientid`),                                  
  UNIQUE KEY `ox_clients_account_id` (`account_id`),          
  KEY `ox_clients_agencyid` (`agencyid`)                      
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

One client can have many campaigns linked to it.

I have a list of campaignids with me , what I want is a list of distinct clientids for those campaigns.

The query that I am using is:

```sql
SELECT clients.* 
    FROM clients  
    JOIN campaigns ON clients.clientid = campaigns.clientid
    WHERE campaigns.is_deleted=0 
        AND campaignid in (2325,2395)
        AND clients.is_deleted=0 
    GROUP BY clients.clientid
```

The EXPLAIN output that it gives is :

```
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+-------------------------------+---------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table     | type  | possible_keys                 | key     | key_len| ref                      | rows| Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+-------------------------------+---------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1  |    SIMPLE   | campaigns | range | PRIMARY,ox_campaigns_clientid | PRIMARY | 3      |             NULL         | 2   | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
| 1  |    SIMPLE   | clients   | eq_ref| PRIMARY                       | PRIMARY | 3      | openx.campaigns.clientid | 1   | Using where
```

Why it is using temporary and filesorting for this query ?

Comment: What is the GROUP BY for?

Comment: @Strawberry , actually one client can have multiple campaigns linked to it , and I want only distinct client information for the corresponding campaign ids

Comment: Use DISTINCT for that. Under certain circumstances, GROUP BY will produce unexpected results. Although, MySQL forgives the activity, GROUP BY should not be used in the absence of any aggregating functions. Note that this is not however a performance issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is using filesort because of the `group by`.  You can prevent this by using an `exists` clause for what you are doing:

```sql
SELECT c.* 
FROM clients c 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM campaigns ca
              WHERE ca.clientid = c.clientid AND
                    ca.is_deleted = 0 AND
                    ca.campaignid IN (2325,2395)
             )
      AND c.is_deleted = 0;
```

You have an index on `campaigns_clientid(clientid)`, so this should use the index.  A better index would be `campaigns_clientid(clientid, is_deleted, campaign_id)`.  This index "covers" the subquery.  In other words, the engine will only use the index and not have to read in the data pages for that table.

Comment: @debaShish If you think an answer is correct please mark it right.